# How can I send repeated / multiple copies of attachments using sendgrid?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

When I send an array with multiple copies of the same attachment in base64, I receive an e-mail with just a single one. It's as if sendgrid doesn't allow repeated attachments somehow:

```
const sendGridRaw: [ClientResponse, unknown] = await sendGrid.send({
   to: email,
   from: infoFrom,
   subject,
   html: msg,
   attachments,
});
```

Where `attachments` are a base64 version of:

```
const attachmentUrls: string[] = [
   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abrahamcalf/programming-languages-logos/master/src/programming-languages.png",
   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abrahamcalf/programming-languages-logos/master/src/programming-languages.png",
];
```

When I receive the e-mail, I get only one attachment instead of those two:

[image]

I've verified the contents of the `attachments`, there are indeed 2 base64 strings. Why does that happen?

Comment: Can I ask what the use case for two identical attachments might be? If it is a necessity, have you tried passing different filenames, or different content IDs for each attachment? Check out the [list of properties an attachment can have here in the API reference](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send).

Comment: It was just a test actually. I've discovered the problem, it's the filename indeed. I can use the same file with different filenames, that both arrive normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SendGrid does not allow multiple attachments with the same name. You can set a different `filename` for the attachments in the API request. For example, the below shows two of the same attachment, but with two different filenames.

```js
  const attachments = [
    {
      content: 'PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sIGxhbmc9ImVuIj4KCiAgICA8aGVhZD4KICAgICAgICA8bWV0YSBjaGFyc2V0PSJVVEYtOCI+CiAgICAgICAgPG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iWC1VQS1Db21wYXRpYmxlIiBjb250ZW50PSJJRT1lZGdlIj4KICAgICAgICA8bWV0YSBuYW1lPSJ2aWV3cG9ydCIgY29udGVudD0id2lkdGg9ZGV2aWNlLXdpZHRoLCBpbml0aWFsLXNjYWxlPTEuMCI+CiAgICAgICAgPHRpdGxlPkRvY3VtZW50PC90aXRsZT4KICAgIDwvaGVhZD4KCiAgICA8Ym9keT4KCiAgICA8L2JvZHk+Cgo8L2h0bWw+Cg==',
      filename: 'index.html',
      type: 'text/html',
      disposition: 'attachment'
    },
    {
      content: 'PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sIGxhbmc9ImVuIj4KCiAgICA8aGVhZD4KICAgICAgICA8bWV0YSBjaGFyc2V0PSJVVEYtOCI+CiAgICAgICAgPG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iWC1VQS1Db21wYXRpYmxlIiBjb250ZW50PSJJRT1lZGdlIj4KICAgICAgICA8bWV0YSBuYW1lPSJ2aWV3cG9ydCIgY29udGVudD0id2lkdGg9ZGV2aWNlLXdpZHRoLCBpbml0aWFsLXNjYWxlPTEuMCI+CiAgICAgICAgPHRpdGxlPkRvY3VtZW50PC90aXRsZT4KICAgIDwvaGVhZD4KCiAgICA8Ym9keT4KCiAgICA8L2JvZHk+Cgo8L2h0bWw+Cg==',
      filename: 'index2.html',
      type: 'text/html',
      disposition: 'attachment'
    }
  ];
```